# How to test a PHP source code for SQL Injection (Without Automatic Tools)?

Tags: mysql

I want to check a PHP source code for sql injection without using tools.
I don't want to check a website, I want to check a source in Local host.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to make yourself the inyection.

check here (for theory): http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Here (for a Walkthrough): http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html

maybe its a hard way but if you learn to do sql-injection you´ll be able to check the security of your own sites with no external tools.

You also may whant to chek this other question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)